search for a string text pattern in all github workflow previous run logs using curl or Invoke-Request
i have github actions workflow pipeline that ran 80+ times in the past 25 days.
It patches JDK on hosts by picking hostnames from the database. The hostname gets logged in the github workflow run logs / output.
The challenge i have now is given a hostname "myhost17", how can i find the github workflow run URL so i could go back check the output.
Opening all 80+ pipeline runs is tedious and i m looking for a better solution to the problem.
The below script helps me get the URL for each run for a particular workflow but the logs for each of them is not showing.
#!/bin/bash

# Run the command and store the output in a variable
output=$(curl -u megithubuser:<github-token> -s "https://api.github.com/repos/mybank/heal/actions/workflows/java-patching.yml/runs" | grep -i ' "url": ' | grep -i runs | awk -F'"' '{print $4}')

# Loop over each URL in the output
while IFS= read -r url; do
  # Append /logs to the URL
  url_with_logs="${url}/logs"
  # Perform actions on each URL
  echo "Processing URL: \"$url_with_logs\""
  curl -u megithubuser:<github-token> -s $url_with_logs
done <<< "$output"

Output:
Processing URL: "https://api.github.com/repos/mybank/heal/actions/runs/8934576962/logs"
curl -u megithubuser:<github-token> -s "https://api.github.com/repos/mybank/heal/actions/runs/8934576962/logs"
Processing URL: "https://api.github.com/repos/mybank/heal/actions/runs/8934231577/logs"
curl -u megithubuser:<github-token> -s "https://api.github.com/repos/mybank/heal/actions/runs/8934231577/logs"
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/actions/workflow-runs#download-workflow-run-logs"
}

Kindly suggest.

GH CLI tool could be helpful here. For me this gh run view RUN_ID --log shows logs in plain text.  You could try to fetch all workflow runs gh run list -w WORKFLOW_ID --json databaseId --jq '.[] | .databaseId' and iterate and check logs with gh run view RUN_ID --log | grep 'YOUR_STRING' command?

Using GH CLI tool (available out of the box in GH Actions) may be of help here. There is a gh run view <ID> --log command that can show plain text log from workflow run. You can combine it with grep and gh run list and do something like this:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

workflow_id=schedule-staging-google-drive-cleanup.yml
limit=100
grep_for="c032dcb8cf4306f6e430e84787a5e18495d91135"


while IFS= read -r line ; do
  run_id=$(echo  "$line" | jq '.databaseId')
  run_url=$(echo  "$line" | jq -r '.url')
  echo "PROCESSING RUN ID: $run_id"

  if gh run view $run_id --log | grep -q "$grep_for"; then
    echo "STRING WAS FOUND IN WORKFLOW RUN: $run_url"
  fi

done <<< $(gh run list -w $workflow_id --json databaseId,url --jq '.[] | tostring' --limit $limit)

Results are like this:
$ bash script.sh
PROCESSING RUN ID: 9087981885
STRING WAS FOUND IN WORKFLOW RUN: https://github.com/org/repo/actions/runs/9087981885
PROCESSING RUN ID: 8903386285
PROCESSING RUN ID: 8682343064
PROCESSING RUN ID: 8501955647
PROCESSING RUN ID: 8289348554


To download the GitHub Workflow logs do the following:
1- List the workflow run IDs
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer GITHUB_TOKEN" --request GET "https://GITHUB_SERVER/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/workflows/WORKFLOW/runs" | jq --raw-output '.workflow_runs[] | .id'

2- For each run ID, download the log
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer GITHUB_TOKEN" --location --header "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" --request GET "https://GITHUB_SERVER/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/runs/RUN_ID/logs" --output run-log.zip


i tried you suggestion but the zip file generated does not contain any data i.e is 0 bytes in size.
[wladmin@remhost ~]$ curl -u megithubuser:<github-token>  -s "https://api.github.com/repos/mybank/heal/actions/runs/8929199993/logs" --output run-log.zip [wladmin@remhost ~]$ echo $? 0 [wladmin@remhost ~]$ ls -ltr run-log.zip -rw-r--r-- 1 wladmin aces 0 May 24 14:56 run-log.zip [wladmin@remhost ~]$ du -sh run-log.zip 0       run-log.zip

You need to use the "--location" option on curl command.

it works when i give --location and i can see a lot of files and folders generated in the ZIP. Could i get the text of the run without generating the folder and files in the ZIP so i could simply search for string pattern in the run output text?

I tried curl -u megithubuser:<github-token> --location -s "https://api.github.com/repos/mybank/heal/actions/runs/8934576962/logs" -o - and also added  -o - -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" but the output recieved is partially encoded unreadable string that looks like this ?ƿ91vd        8Ve@=918&@}daGgg4l\ɚН2VKy{q$&qiIxaej;y] |_ޟi@ȃ;Hȿ(BJhAU<2IXT7;_FǮ@Z۬)6I<(y|$<VP.PףN<h 3P{PKX(APerforming Cleanup  Cleanup-remoteservers/PKX.6~<.F15_Performing Cleanup  Cleanup-remotehostseven.txtPKXB::b7Performing Cleanup

You can use zipgrep, or something like that, to search in the downloaded zip files.
